# String after find recognized as one parameter

Tags: bash, shell, find

I've recreated a cluttered script I've posted a few days ago, and it's much more cleaner. Now I have the following problem:

My script creates a variable string, depending on all the given arguments, because part of the parameters need to be transformed into find parameters.

For example my script creates the following:

```
FINDVAR="/home /ex -type f -name \*.sh"
```

When I try to do the following:
`find $FINDVAR` or `find ${FINDVAR}` or even `$(find $FINDVAR)`
I receive no output.

However when I `echo $FINDVAR`
and paste the output after a find, it works perfectly!

I also tried to do

```
find "$FINDVAR"
```

But that gives me

> find: `/home /ex  -type f -name \*.sh': No such file or directory

So, that recognizes the string as 1 parameter.

Any solution? I've been stuck on it for a few hours now

**Edit: Can't really find it, maybe one of you can have a look at it? I left out the long Dutch echo's**

```
#!/bin/bash

#FUNCTIONS
#Foutmelding
charfout(){
  echo "Uw ingevoerde eerste letter met argument -l is ongeldig."
  echo "Gebruik: $0 -e <extensie> -l <a>/<a-c>"
}

extfout() {
  echo 1>&2;
  echo 1>&2;
  exit
 }

#Help
help() {
  echo
  echo "--- Help ---"
  echo
  exit
}


#Opties in getopt instellen + argumenten in volgorde plaatsen (mappen achter case-opties)
OPTS=$(getopt -o e:hl:b:f:s: -l "help,nn,nr,fout" -n "ExamenScript" -- "$@");
eval set -- "$OPTS";

#Case doorlopen om opties aan respectievelijke variabelen toe te wijzen
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    -e)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        BESTANDSEXTENSIE=$1;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    -h|--help)
      shift;
      help;
      ;;
    -l)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        BEGINLETTER=$1;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    -b)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        BLOCKDEVICE=$1;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    --nn)
      shift;
      NONUMBERS=true;
      ;;
    --nr)
      shift;
      NORECURSION=true;
      ;;
    -f|--fout)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        FOUTLOG=true;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    -s)
      shift;
      if [ -n "$1" ]; then
        ZOEKEN=$1;
        shift;
      fi
      ;;
    --)
      shift;
      break;
      ;;
  esac
done

#De overige argumenten, ergo de te-doorzoeken-folders, in een array plaatsen
TEDOORZOEKENFOLDERS=("$@")

#De array van folders als eerste argumenten van de find functie opgeven
#FINDARGUMENTEN=$(printf "%s " "${TEDOORZOEKENFOLDERS[@]}")

#Nagaan of er een block device gemount dient te worden
if [[ $BLOCKDEVICE ]]; then
  echo "Gelieve admin rechten te geven om het block-device te kunnen mounten."
  sudo mount /dev/$BLOCKDEVICE /mnt
  TEDOORZOEKENFOLDERS+=(" /mnt") #Pad van gemounte drive aan array toevoegen
fi

#Beargumenteren dat er naar bestanden moet gezocht worden (type -f)
FINDARGUMENTEN="-type f"

#Indien de no-recursion vlag gebruikt is, enkel level 1 mappen toestaan
if [[ $NORECURSION ]]; then
  FINDARGUMENTEN=$FINDARGUMENTEN" -maxdepth 1"
fi

#De extensie implementeren door een naamfilter aan find toe te voegen
#Indien geen extensie opgegeven, foutmelding
if [[ $BESTANDSEXTENSIE ]]; then
  FINDARGUMENTEN=$FINDARGUMENTEN" -name \*.${BESTANDSEXTENSIE}"
else
  extfout
fi

#Nagaan hoeveel karakters er aan het -l argument toegewezen zijn
case ${#BEGINLETTER} in
  0) #Niets toegewezen
    ;;
  1) FINDARGUMENTEN=$FINDARGUMENTEN" -name ${BEGINLETTER}*" #Beginnen met een letter
    ;;
  3) FINDARGUMENTEN=$FINDARGUMENTEN" -name [${BEGINLETTER}]*" #Beginnenn met een letter-range
    ;;
  *) charfout
    ;;
  esac

#Indien de no-numbers vlag gebruikt is, nummers verbieden in de bestandsnaam
if [[ $NONUMBERS ]]; then
  FINDARGUMENTEN=$FINDARGUMENTEN" \! -name '*[0-9]*'"
fi

find "${TEDOORZOEKENFOLDERS[@]} $FINDARGUMENTEN"
```

Comment: try running your `find`command without the quotes: find ${FINDVAR}

Answer (score 3):

Try using an array:

```
FINDVAR=( /home /ex -type f -name \*.sh )
find "${FINDVAR[@]}"
```

That should properly handle all the arguments with appropriate escaping/quoting.

---

You need something like

```
FINDARGUMENTEN=( -type f )

if [[ $NORECURSION ]]; then
    FINDARGUMENTEN+=( -maxdepth 1 )
fi

if [[ $BESTANDSEXTENSIE ]]; then
    FINDARGUMENTEN+=( -name "\\*.${BESTANDSEXTENSIE}" )
fi

case ${#BEGINLETTER} in
    1) FINDARGUMENTEN+=( -name "${BEGINLETTER}\\* ) ;;
    3) FINDARGUMENTEN+=( -name "[${BEGINLETTER}]\\*" ) ;;
esac

if [[ $NONUMBERS ]]; then
    FINDARGUMENTEN+=( '\!' -name '*[0-9]*' )
fi

find "${TEDOORZOEKENFOLDERS[@]}" "${FINDARGUMENTEN[@]}"
```

I'm not certain of the double backslashes -- you'll have to experiment. You may need 1 or 2 or 3 backslashes

While you're testing, do `set -x` so you can see what bash is doing.

Comment: That's something I had in mind, but it would require me to change a lot in the code, but it's probably more logical after all! I'll let you know how it worked out! :)

Comment: It doesn't work at all, I tried adding arguments to the array by using FINDVAR+="argument", but the script works only half.

Comment: To append elements to an array: `FINDVAR+=( "argument" )` -- with the parentheses

Comment: And it's not just logical, it's functional. As you've experienced, it's very hard to get right with string concatenation.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! Looks better, find recognizes the arguments as folders aswell, but I think it's fixable by combining an array with my folders and a string for my arguments!
Or will I get the same error where find interprets the string as a folder path?

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you could disable pathname expansion with `set -f`:

```
set -f

FINDVAR="/home /ex -type f -name *.sh"
find $FINDVAR
```

This works because bash never tries to replace the `*.sh` with file names and just leaves it as is.

Comment: I'll try that when I have to change things on my exam. I tried lot's of things and just used multiple $VARS. Wish me luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
FINDVAR="/home /ex -type f -name *.sh"
eval "find $FINDVAR"
```

Comment: Unjustified use of eval. See better answer below.